# Edge.Js: How to execute multiple callbacks within nodejs

Tags: node.js, edge.js

I have a .Net app that executes JavaScript using EdgeJs.
The js script executes some logic and acquires some data, then it should return the data back to the .Net app. There may be a lot of data, so I want to pass it back to the .Net app in chunks.

My .Net app:

```
private async Task<Object> CallNodeFunction(Object input)
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException = null;
        try
        {
            var func = Edge.Func(JSFunction);

            var data= await func(input);

            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             // sophisticated error handling
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Basicly I want to do something like that (simple example):

```
function start(params, callback) {

    getTheData(params).then(function (response) { callback(null, response); }); // Chunk 1

    getTheData(params).then(function (response) { callback(null, response); }); // Chunk 2

    getTheData(params).then(function (response) { callback(null, response); }); // Chunk 3

}
```

as you can see I'm executing the callback 3 times, but I can't find a way to make Edge.Js handle all the 3 responses.

Any Ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

.net is synchronous, so its only going to call your node function only once, and then its going to move on to the next line and your node function will not get called again.

But, as you have mentioned, you want to recieve the data in chunks, so you will have to apply this chunking logic in your .net code and pass the offset as a parameter to the node function, for node to fetch the next chunk based on the offset and pass the data again.